# Adding flavour based dependencies in Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

Hi I am trying to add some dependencies based on flavour in my Android project. My code looks like as follow

```
android {
    
    productFlavors {
        customextended {}
        customini {}
    }
}


dependencies {
    customextendedImplimentation 'dependency_name'
}
```

Above code throws following error

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method customextendedImplimentation() for arguments [dependency_name] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**as follows**：

```
android {
    
    productFlavors {
        customextended {}
        customini {}
    }
}


dependencies {
    customextendedImplementation 'dependency_name'
}
```

**your single misspelling**

Comment: After correcting spell it worked. Thanks.